# How to convert time into hours( in decimal)?

Tags: oracle

I need to calculate working hours based on the time given in database. I already managed to calculate it but seems like it does not include the second.

```
  SUBSTR (
   (ROUND ((( 
   (FLOOR (((MAX (g.actual_time)) - (MIN (g.actual_time)))* 24))*60)
   + (MOD (FLOOR(((MAX (g.actual_time))-(MIN (g.actual_time)))*24*60),
   60)))/60,2)|| ' '),1,18)WH,
```

Expected

```
------------------------

login : 2019-10-10 23:11:49

Logout : 2019-10-10 23:57:46

WH : 0.77
```

Actual

```
---------------------------

login : 2019-10-10 23:11:49

Logout : 2019-10-10 23:57:46

WH : 0.75
```

Comment: Simply try `(logout - login) * 24`

Comment: thank you, its working now. Using (logout - login) * 24